# mingw g++ vector<T>::insert bug

Tags: c++, stl, vector, iterator

```
vector<int> nums;
nums.push_back(0);
nums.push_back(1);
nums.push_back(2);
nums.push_back(3);

vector<int>::iterator it = nums.begin();
it++;

cout << "it points to " << *(it) << endl;
for(vector<int>::iterator jt = nums.begin(); jt != nums.end(); jt++) {
    cout << (*jt) << endl;
}
cout << endl;

nums.insert(it, 100500);
cout << ">> insert(it, 100500)" << endl << endl;

cout << "it points to " << *(it) << endl;
for(vector<int>::iterator jt = nums.begin(); jt != nums.end(); jt++) {
    cout << (*jt) << endl;
}
cout << endl;

it++;
cout << ">> it++" << endl << endl;

cout << "it points to " << *(it) << endl;
for(vector<int>::iterator jt = nums.begin(); jt != nums.end(); jt++) {
    cout << (*jt) << endl;
}
cout << endl;

nums.insert(it, 100800);
cout << ">> insert(it, 100800)" << endl << endl;

cout << "it points to " << *(it) << endl;
for(vector<int>::iterator jt = nums.begin(); jt != nums.end(); jt++) {
    cout << (*jt) << endl;
}
cout << endl;

it++;
cout << ">> it++" << endl << endl;

cout << "it points to " << *(it) << endl;
for(vector<int>::iterator jt = nums.begin(); jt != nums.end(); jt++) {
    cout << (*jt) << endl;
}
cout << endl;
```

returns

```
it points to 1
0
1
2
3

>> insert(it, 100500)

it points to 1
0
100500
1
2
3

>> it++

it points to 2
0
100500
1
2
3

>> insert(it, 100800)

it points to 100800
134352185
0
100500
1
2
3

>> it++

it points to 2
134352185
0
100500
1
2
3
```

I cant understand anything. help!

mingw g++ 4.5.0 win32

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you insert a new element into a `vector`, any iterators to elements after the insertion position are invalidated and if a reallocation occurs then all iterators into the container are invalidated.  A reallocation occurs any time that `v.capacity() - v.size()` is less than the number of elements you are trying to insert.

When an iterator is invalidated, it means that the iterator can no longer be used.  It is invalid.

This overload of `insert` returns a new iterator to the inserted element, so you can replace this:

```
nums.insert(it, 100500);
```

with this:

```
it = nums.insert(it, 100500);
```

The rules for when iterators are invalidated are different for each container and you must be careful to understand them.  One of the best references for the STL is the [SGI STL documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/table_of_contents.html).  The iterator invalidation rules are usually listed in a footnote on each of the container documentation pages.

Note that the SGI STL documentation is not the official documentation for the C++ Standard Library and there are some subtle differences, but usually those differences are not particularly important; one thing to note is that some pieces of the SGI STL are not included in the C++ Standard Library and some parts of the C++ Standard Library are not part of the SGI STL.

Comment: It's best not to call the C++ Standard Library "the STL" at all, partially for the stated reason and mostly because that's not its name.

Comment: @Tomalak:  It is common and accepted practice to use the name "STL" to refer to the components of the C++ Standard Library that originated in the original STL library designed by Alexander Stepanov.  This includes the container, iterator, algorithm, and functor library components of the C++ Standard Library.

Comment: I am well aware that it is common, but I dispute the "accepted". I and many others are attempting to weed out the plague of its misuse!

Comment: @Tomalak: You and "many others" are just being pedantic and obnoxious. It's like trying to argue that the phrase "const reference" is incorrect because there is no such thing as a const-qualified reference. There is no confusion today when the term STL is used because everyone means the C++ Standard Library components; no one is using the original SGI library anymore: it's ancient history. Respected authors and C++ experts like Herb, Andrei, and Scott use the term STL in its broader meaning.  There are 2,100 questions tagged [stl] here; I'd be surprised if five of them were about the SGI STL.

Comment: Unfortunately, the idea that nobody means the original SGI STL any more is complete rubbish. STLPort is very popular and is a port of the STL, not of the C++ Standard Library. With the growth of C++0x the differences between the two become even more pronounced. I remain astounded that so many people so militantly defend the inappropriate use of this name, and disappointed that so many prolific authors follow suit.

Comment: (Also, calling someone "obnoxious" on SO is hardly conducive to a pleasant discussion. Please read the FAQ: it's considered best to "be nice".)

Comment: @Tomalak: Concerning STLport, you are absolutely wrong:  "STLport is implementation of C++ Standard Library, as described in the INTERNATIONAL STANDARD ISO/IEC 14882:1998(E) and latest ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E)." That's from the STLport website.  Should they rename themselves?  Concerning C++0x, yes, as with all of the new features being added to the language and the Standard Library, we have to be careful to explain that not all library implementations support any or all of the new features. It's tedious, but it would be just as tedious regardless what we call it.

Comment: Ah, so it is! The last time I looked at STLport their front page said (and you can still see this on the stlport.org Google cache) "A port of the original STL to many platforms. Derived from the SGI implementation, changes are incorporated regularly." However, this site now seems to have vanished. http://stlport.sourceforge.net/Home.shtml does indeed indicate a compliance to the standard.

Then this has sadly become just one more example of the sad spread of an inaccurate, vague and inappropriate term, whose *careful* use only shall I continue to champion.

Comment: (Yes, they should definitely rename themselves. I'm not going to ask them to any more than I'd bother asking Meyers to rename his book "Effective STL". Doesn't make it any more right.)

Comment: @Tomalak: "Effective STL" only deals with the STL (that parts of the standard library which come from the original SGI STL), not with the whole of the standard library, so it is not a misnomer. (From what I know of Scott, it would have surprised me if he got this terminology wrong.)

Comment: @sbi: Even those parts based on the STL are not the STL themselves.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug. You failed to properly read the `std::vector` documentation before leaping to the conclusion that the software was in error; in fact, vector insertions invalidate all iterators.